# Angular, `required` input field for digits between 0 to 100 and/or starting with dot (.)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

[after inserting the expression given by you I am finding a lexer error check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nr32.png)

```html
<div class="col-md-6 nopad">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label text-left">(%)</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control"
               ng-pattern="^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)\[0-9]?\[0-9](?:\.\[0-9]\[0-9]?)?$"
               ng-blur="($ctrl.expenseForm.insurance_percent.$valid)?$ctrl.updateAmountValue('insurance',$ctrl.expenses.total_cfcost):''" 
               id="insurance_percent" name="insurance_percent"
               ng-model="$ctrl.expenses.insurance_percent"> 
        <div class="help-block"
             ng-messages="$ctrl.expenseForm.insurance_percent.$error"
             ng-if="$ctrl.expenseForm.insurance_percent.$dirty">
            <p class="text-danger"
               ng-message="required">This field is required.</p>
            <p class="text-danger"
               ng-message="pattern">Value should between 0 to 100.</p> 
        </div>                                    
    </div>
</div>
```

It should accept decimal numbers or validate numbers which are between 0 to 100 as well as it should accept the decimal values that begin with a dot(.) that is no need of 0 at the start for a decimal number and also should be between 0 and 100.

Comment: Use `ng-pattern="/^(?:\.\d+|[1-9]?[0-9](?:\.\d+)?|100(?:\.0+)?)$/"` or `ng-pattern="/^0*(?:\.\d+|[1-9]?[0-9](?:\.\d+)?|100(?:\.0+)?)$/"` to allow optional leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe try a slightly simpler regex here, it's not a particularly complex problem and it'll make maintainability easier.

Something like `^[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]+)?$`

```
^                              Start of string
 [0-9]{0,2}                    Anywhere between 0 and 2 numbers
           (\.                 Start matching group and look for decimal point
              [0-9]+           Any numbers after decimal point (must be at least one)
                    )?$        End matching group, match it either 0 or 1 times and ensure string end.
```

Note that this'll also match a blank string, meaning you won't get a warning on no input!

https://regex101.com/r/IUM5YK/2

Answer (score 0):

`^(?=[0-9.])[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]+)?$|^100$`
I divided the problem in 4 parts
1) It should be something `(?=[0-9.])` a lookahead to match a digit or a dot
2) The integer part : `[0-9]{0,2}` which is optionnal
3) The decimal part : `(\.[0-9]+)?` which is optionnal
4) the 100 case

Comment: i have updated the same expression to my code but i am not finding any luck i am getting a lexer error

Comment: Try with this one maybe : `^(?:(?:100)|(?=[0-9.])[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]+)?)$`